# How can I avoid repeating handlebar templates in cshtml on MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

I have handlebars and I want them to be rendered conditionally.

F.e pseudo code:

```
if(condition)
{
   <script id="template-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    ...................
   </script>

   <script id="template-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    ...............
   </script>

}
else
{ 
   if(condition2)
   {
     <script id="template-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      ................
     </script>
   }
   else
   {
     <script id="template-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     ..........
     </script>
   }
}
```

so I do not want to repeat template1 and template2 handlebars in cshtml. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `if (condition || condition2) { /* render template-1' */ } if (condition || !condition2) { /* render template-2 */ }` ? Or, assuming you are using the Razor View Engine, how about defining [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/timlee/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax) for the rendering of each template?

Comment: Yes that is the single way, I have more nested conditions but it looks  I have to repeat just conditions instead of scripts, better than reperating scripts.